# Exclude a webpage from a search result when a user uses a specific keyword

Tags: html, search

Consider a webpage with a keyword "A". I want to make sure that this page will not be in the search result when a user searches with a keyword "A". Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Remove the keyword "A" from the webpage

Comment: No. This is not an option for some reason.

Comment: You can use noindex to ask the search engines not to index the page at all. But you can't tell them not to match you against particular keywords.

Comment: This is the standard answer. But I need a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest excluding all keywords three letters or less that are found in the dictionary. You could also setup a blacklist table of keywords that should not be used for finding search results.

Comment: Thank you. Actually there is only keyword that I would like to exclude. Let this keyword be "Abracadabra." That is, I do not want this webpage to show up in the search result when a user searches with the keyword "Abracadabra."

Comment: In that case you could just take the raw search term in php and str_replace for the keyword. `$searchText = str_replace("Abracadabra","",$searchText);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I want to make sure: (1) I do not want to delete "Abracadabra" from the webpage, but (2) I want the webpage from the search results of "Abracadabra." Please advise.

Comment: I thought you wanted to exclude the keyword "abracadabra" from the search terms so it would not show up in the results. Your last comment makes it sound like you want to be able to search "abracadabra" and find the webpage containing "abracadabra". What exactly are you aiming to happen? Provide user input, input actually searched for, and a sample result if you can.

Comment: You are right. I should have said I *do not* want the webpage to show up in the search results of "Abracadabra."

Comment: So in summary, your solution is to put <?php $searchText = str_replace("Abracadabra","",$searchText);; ?>. Correct?

Comment: @Bistro Elan you are asking an impossible question. The only ways would be to remove or (obfuscate somehow) the keywords from the content or turn off indexing completely for that page. Search engines will index the content they see.

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to make (1) the content that the search engines will see be different from (2) the original content on html?

Comment: With a lot of work you could for example use images or some JavaScript for a particular word so it doesn't get indexed but even if you do manage to trick the search engines you have only done half the work because you would reduce the words weighting to zero rather than making it negative. You can have negative keywords in a google adwords campaign tho https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453972?hl=en